# How to cotinuosly append data from DB2 server to sqlite using preferably django and if nothing else then python alone code

Tags: python, sql, django, db2, migrate

I am writing a django website that has some reports that pulls data based on DB2 database. Since I have only read only access to that database, I want the data from DB2 to be continuosly appended (or appended at intervals of lets say 20 minutes) to sqlite database being used by django. 
Now I am totally new to python as well hence I am blank with what should I use for this.
Is there any django method that can be implemented or should I write a python only script to copy the data.

Lets say I have a database with fields - DEAL,BUSINESS,CUSTID,REPID,REPNAME in DB2 (I don't have any primary key here since the database if very old). I want to continuisly copy this data from DB2 to Sqlite. What should be the simplest code?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that Db2 for Linux Unix windows, Db2 for zOS, Db2 for IBM i, and Db2 Warehouse are all different inside, so, if you need further information, specify type and version of Db2.

For moving data **periodically** you have many options. @Iakovos_Belonias suggestion is one of them.  Your main challenge will be recognizing new rows, rows being changed, and rows being deleted.  If source table is not very large, you can copy it completely, but if the source table is large, you will have to try a smarter mechanism.  If this is the case, please put comment or open a new question.

For moving data **near-real-time**, the best option is by using a Change Data Capture (CDC) application such as IBM Infosphere Data Replication or Oracle Golden Gate, among others.  I think there is not a free CDC application (except for licenses with limitations that will not cover your need), and commercial CDC applications are offered for Db2 versions still under supported.

I hope this help...

Comment: Thanks for your elaborative responce, I really found this giving me some directions. As you asked about version, the DB2 server is of IBM I Series working on AS400. I can only take ODBC connections to that server and no direct connections possible with any driver (I tried some python drivers, maybe some licence issue was there). Again I want to keep all this cost free so I think CDC won't help. I can't recognize new rows being the fact that the DB2 is not made with timestamps all I can do is rrn sql commands on that, that might help for new rows, or maybe not.

Comment: Well, if you can connect to Db2 for IBM i (iSeries, AS/400) through ODBC, it means that you can also connect through JDBC and can use any tool that works on ODBC/JDBC including most of ETL tools (either free or fee based).  On the other hand, Old School IBM i developers used to create tables without key (they call them Physical Files) and create a kind of index+view with unique key (they call them Logical File).  If you can identify if that particular table has a "keyed logical file" on top of it, so you have a Unique Index.

Comment: Regarding RRN, you can use it as PK, but keeping in mind that if, for some reason, they reorganize the table (what they call Reorganize physical file member), the RRN will change as records will change their position in the table.

Comment: Just an extra comment.  Ask the table owner if that table (or physical file) is multimember...  Multimember is a concept not present in other RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time on this, your comments cleared a lot of concepts.

Answer (score 0):

[Sql alchemy module is what you need](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

[And for peridocal tasks what you need is a cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you valuable time on this. I found what you shared really informative. If possible can you please help me by giving some code example directly related to my requirments? I appreciate your work though.

Comment: Hi, what kind of coda sample you need ?

Comment: I needed a small code to just copy a whole table from IBM I Series DB2 using odbc connection into sqlite on some intervals. Let it be any simple example.

Comment: If you have the code ready and you only want to execute the script periodically then what you want is a cron job. Google search your OS and how to do a cron job and you will find plenty simples examples. If I had any experience with IBM I would told you exactly what you want because I don't have any experience with these systems I can't tell you for sure, I am sorry.

Comment: No problem, I really appreciate your help and support here.